# pandas: find the category difference between groups

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have the following code:

`df.groupby('result')['col_A'].value_counts(normalize = True)`, which gives the following output:

```
Won    X                        0.500000
       Y                        0.437500
       Z                        0.062500
Lost   X                        0.693878
       Y                        0.204082
       Z                        0.102041
```

I need to find the sum of differences of each category (X, Y, Z) between the two groups (Won, Lost). i.e.

```
diff =  abs(0.500000 - 0.693878) + abs(0.437500 - 0.204082) + abs(0.062500 - 0.102041)
```

Other than output the values, then do the computation element by element, is there an elegant way to achieve this in pandas directly? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
(df.loc['Won'] - df.loc['Lost']).abs().sum().values[0]
```

Output:

```
0.466837
```

Comment: the df here is the original df? where do we specify 'col_A'? Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry... df here was the result of the groupby which was given in the question.

Comment: But  type(df.groupby('result')['col_A'].value_counts(normalize = True) ) is  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> ... so which part should I convert to a data frame? Thanks!

Comment: If I do: df_gp = df.groupby('result')['col_A'].value_counts(normalize = True) ).to_frame() , then (df.loc['Won'] - df.loc['Lost']).abs().sum().values[0] gives the error: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Comment: It seems to work sometimes if just do: (df.loc['Won'] - df.loc['Lost']).abs().sum(). But it fails sometimes as the category in df.loc['Won'] and df.loc['Lost'] are in different orders ... is there a way to make their order consistent?

Comment: You can change a series to a dataframe using `to_frame`.